# how do i populate using mongoose middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

````
  {
    cartItems: [
      {
        product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "product" },
        quantity: Number,
        color: String,
        price: Number,
      },
    ],
    totalPrice: Number,
    totalPriceAfterDiscount: Number,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// @desc query mongoose middleware to populate
CartSchema.pre(/find/, function (next) {
  this.populate("user");
  next();
});```

it throw this error
````

MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "user".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)\n    at Connection.model (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:1236:13)\n    at _getModelFromConn (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/populate/getModelsMapForPopulate.js:581:15)\n    at addModelNamesToMap (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/populate/getModelsMapForPopulate.js:507:17)\n    at getModelsMapForPopulate (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/populate/getModelsMapForPopulate.js:198:7)\n    at populate (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4679:21)\n    at _populate (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4639:5)\n    at /home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4616:5\n    at promiseOrCallback (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:11:14)\n    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1266:10)\n    at Model.populate (/home/melewasy/projects/full-E-commerce/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4614:23)"

```
i tried this line instead of mongoose middleware
```

```
let x = await Cart.findById(cart._id).populate("user");
```

Comment: The error says there isn't a schema named `user`. Have you defined such a schema?

Answer (score 0):

import the user schema

```js
const User = require("file_path")
```

and add it to the populate method

```js
let x = await Cart.findById(cart._id).populate("user", User);
```